# Windows - pip install mysql-python error

Tags: python, mysql

I have a virtual environment and i try to install:

`pip install mysql-python`

but i get the following error:

```
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
error: INCLUDE environment variable is empty
```

what can i do?

Comment: why don't you download pre built connector from this link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5

Comment: Have you activated the environment? If not activate it and then see the compatible version. Before that try conda install python=3.5". I guess you would be using anaconda.